# Inequality on matrix trace

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, matrix-analysis

Consider the following inequality of Lemma 1 arising in [The law of large numbers for quantum stochastic filtering and control of many-particle systems](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S0040577921070084) :

$$\Big|tr(L\gamma LB) - \frac{1}{2}tr(B(L\gamma + \gamma L))tr(BL + \gamma L) + tr(B\gamma)tr(BL)tr(\gamma L) \Big| \leq 5||L||^2 tr\big((Id-\gamma)B\big),$$

where $\gamma$ is a ($n\times n$) **density matrix of rank one**  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix for the definition of density matrix), $B$ is a **density matrix** and $L$ a **hermitian matrix**. My question is whether the above inequality holds (up to some constant in front of $tr\big((Id-\gamma)B\big)$) by assuming only that $\gamma$ is a **density matrix** (with the assumptions on $\gamma, L$ unchanged)?

PS : Without loss of generality we may assume that $\gamma$ is diagonal with its diagonal elements $\gamma_1,\ldots, \gamma_n\in\mathbb R_+$ s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^N \gamma_i=1$.

PS2 : Denote respectively the l.h.s. and r.h.s. by

$$f(\gamma):=\Big|tr(L\gamma LB) - \frac{1}{2}tr(B(L\gamma + \gamma L))tr(BL + \gamma L) + tr(B\gamma)tr(BL)tr(\gamma L) \Big|$$

and

$$g(\gamma):=5||L||^2 tr\big((Id-\gamma)B\big).$$

Following the hint of Narutaka OZAWA, I try to reduce the general case to the case where $\gamma$ has rank one. The difficulty for me is that $g$ is affine while $f$ is not (it is even not trivial for me to show $f$ is convex).

Comment: @JosephVanName That's a really unexpected observation. Could you please give more details how computation yields the inverse inequality? I know very few on computer experiments. Many thanks

Comment: What you had is right. I was getting the inequality in the wrong direction.

Comment: Using computer experiments with gradient descent (I used the Flux library in the language Julia). I conjecture the inequality $$|\text{tr}(L\gamma LB)−0.5\cdot \text{tr}(B(L\gamma+\gamma L))\text{tr}(BL+\gamma L)+\text{tr}(B\gamma)\text{tr}(BL)\text{tr}(\gamma L)|\leq \|L\|_p^2\cdot\text{tr}((Id−\gamma)B)⋅4^{1/p}$$ for $1\leq p\leq\infty$ where $\|\cdot\|_p$ denotes the Schatten $p$-norm.

Comment: This is true, but for an uninteresting reason. The $\mathrm{tr}$-norm distance from $\gamma$ (or $B$) to a rank-one projection is dominated by a constant (perhaps $2$) multiple of $\mathrm{tr}((1-\gamma)B)$. Hence the problem reduces to the case where $\gamma$ has rank one (modulo changing the constant in front of $\mathrm{tr}((1-\gamma)B)$ as you suggested).

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Thanks so much for pointing out this. Could you please detail how to prove what you have mentioned? I'm not very familiar with the tricks in matrix analysis and I'm interested in this inequality. Thank you very kindly for your consideration

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA More precisely, "The tr-norm distance from $\gamma$ (or $B$) to a rank-one projection is dominated by a constant (perhaps 2) multiple of $tr((1-\gamma)B)$" is not clear to me. Could you please write the corresponding inequality?

Comment: @Fawen90: We may assume $\gamma=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots)$ with $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\cdots$. Then the only way $\mathrm{tr}(\gamma B)=\sum_i \lambda_i B_{ii}$ is close to $\mathrm{tr}(B)=1$ is $\lambda_1\approx1$.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Thank you Narutaka for your explanation. The difficulty for me is that the r.h.s. of the desired inequality is affine in $\gamma$ while the l.h.s. is not (I don't know how to show it is convex in $\gamma$), see PS2 above. Could you please let me know how to proceed to the case where $\gamma$ has rank one? A detailed solution is highly appreciated and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Let $I^{i,j}$ be the matrix whose only non zero element is $I^{i,j}_{i,j}=1$. Then for $\gamma=\sum_i \gamma_i I^{i,i}$, how can we obtain the estimation $f(\gamma) \le C \sum_i f(\gamma_i I^{i,i})$ for some constant $C$?

Comment: @Fawen90: You misunderstood what I say. Just replace $\gamma=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots)$ everywhere with the rank-one projection $\gamma_1 = \mathrm{diag}(1,0,\ldots)$ by paying the cost $\| \gamma-\gamma_1 \|_{\mathrm{tr}}\le 2(1-\mathrm{tr}(\gamma B))$ at each time.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Thanks a lot for the precision, while I still don't know how to estimate the difference for the terms $tr(L\gamma LB), tr(B(L\gamma + \gamma L))tr(BL + \gamma L), tr(B\gamma)tr(BL)tr(\gamma L), tr\big((Id-\gamma)B\big)$ when replacing $\gamma$ by $\gamma_1$. Do you mind provide more details on the calculus? Many thanks

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA For example, how to estimate the difference $tr\big(L(\gamma-\gamma_1)LB\big)$? Why this estimation allows to derive the desired inequality?

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA More precisely, what is the definition of $\|\gamma-\gamma_1\|_{tr}$? In particular, how can we dominate the difference $|tr((\gamma-\gamma_1) L)|$ in terms of $\|\gamma-\gamma_1\|_{tr}\le 2(1-tr(\gamma B))$?